# Not able to detect the CheckBox checked method in GridView

Tags: vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I am adding the checkbox in gridview.I want to get the third cell value from each row.I am using the button click to post back to server which is outside of the gridview.
My Code:

(ASPX Part)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="8px">
 <ItemTemplate >

                      <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkRow"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
'It is outside of the Gridview
<asp:Button ID="btnGetSelected" runat="server" Text="Get selected records"  OnClick ="GetSelectedRecords" />
```

(Vb.net Part)

```
Protected Sub GetSelectedRecords(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim colSelRowKeys As New Collection
    colSelRowKeys.Clear()
    Dim s As String
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridADFMain.Rows
 If (CType(row.FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox)).Checked Then
            s = row.Cells(3).Text
            colSelRowKeys.Add(s)
 End If
    Next
    Session.Add("colSelRowKeys", colSelRowKeys)
End Sub
```

I am not able to enter the if checked condition.

Comment: Your code looks good, works fine in my test also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code works well in test. Make sure that you are not rebinding your Gridview at post back. In rebinding check boxes values will be overwritten. Check where you databind the gridview, normally in Page_Load, wrap the code in If Not IsPostBack like below:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        'Code to get data
        '    ..........            
        ' BindGridView()
        GridADFMain.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have binded the gridADFMain in my page load.I am able to view the data.My Problem is ,When I click on the button the the click event is also fine.but,the isChecked is not working.

Comment: It is not about binding, it is about rebinding. When you click the button, Page_Load is triggered, and if it does not have `If Not Page.IsPostBack`, it will remove Checked from check box. So when `GetSelectedRecords` is executed, checkbox is is default state, it is no more checked.

Comment: If you post the Page_Load method, probably we could figure out if it is ok.

Comment: I dont have the code with me now.I will try your above comment and post the code tomorrow.Thanks.